# Optimizing the ratio between two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, optimal-control

I have two second-order differential equations describing two systems, both with the same form but different coefficients:

$$ x_v(t) = A_v \frac{d^2u(t)}{dt^2} + B_v \frac{du(t)}{dt} + C_v u(t) - D_v \frac{dx_v(t)}{dt} - \frac{d^2 x_v(t)}{dt^2} $$

$$ x_h(t) = A_h \frac{d^2u(t)}{dt^2} + B_h \frac{du(t)}{dt} + C_h u(t) - D_h \frac{dx_h(t)}{dt} - \frac{d^2 x_h(t)}{dt^2} $$

And I'm trying to select the control function $u(t)$ to maximize one system while minimizing the other; maximize $\int{x_v\ dt}$ (or alternatively the energy integral) while making $x_h$ as close to 0 as possible.

I've tried various optimal control and MPC techniques like iLQR (just makes a step function), pseudospectral optimizers like PSOPT (produces some sensible result with an extremely fine node resolution, but extremely computationally demanding and I can do better by guessing), but I feel like there must be something I'm missing - something about the ratio or the DE that would simplify the problem...

If one system is simply set to a reasonable output and the other to 0, an overdetermined system is obtained, which does not seem super useful.

This problem seems to be similar to a class called "simultaneous stabilization" or "underactuated systems", but the methods don't seem to be particularly applicable.

If anyone has any examples of an equivalent problem or a solution technique, I would be grateful! Thanks!

Ed. per questions:

All coefficients can be assumed to be positive. Both sets of coefficients are similar (whatever that's worth). The time horizon of interest is positive and finite.

The physical context of the problem is called cellular electroporation: [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0302-4598(97)00093-7) is the paper with transfer functions I'm working off of.

Comment: Woud it be possible to narrow down the problem? Such as are the poles and zeros of each system in the left-hand-plane (which I believe would be the case if all coefficients are positive) and are you considering a finite of infinite time horizon?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thanks! edited question with more detail. coefficients are positive, time is finite and >=0. I'm sorry - I messed up the sign of one of the terms the first time, I think it's fixed.

Comment: Without additional constraints or penalty to $u(t)$ I think that this problem is not well posed. Namely, one could use a solution such that $A_h \ddot{u}(t) + B_h \dot{u}(t) + C_h u(t) = 0$ and scale it by any arbitrary large scalar.

Comment: For non-zero initial conditions for $x_h$ this solution might change a bit, but one can always add any arbitrary large scaled signal from my previous comment to a signal that drives $x_h(t)$ to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As

$$
\cases{
X_v(s) = \frac{A_v s^2+B_v s+ C_v}{s^2+sD_v + 1}U(s) + \frac{\dot x_v(0)+ s x_v(0)}{s^2+sD_v + 1}\\
X_h(s) = \frac{A_h s^2+B_h s+ C_h}{s^2+sD_h + 1}U(s) + \frac{\dot x_h(0)+ s x_h(0)}{s^2+sD_h + 1}
}
$$

we have

$$
\cases{
x_v(t) = \int \Phi_v(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{\dot x_v(0)+ s x_v(0)}{s^2+sD_v + 1}\right]\\
x_h(t) = \int \Phi_h(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{\dot x_h(0)+ s x_h(0)}{s^2+sD_h + 1}\right]\\
}
$$

Here $\Phi_v(\tau), \Phi_h(\tau), \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{\dot x_v(0)+ s x_v(0)}{s^2+sD_v + 1}\right], \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{\dot x_h(0)+ s x_h(0)}{s^2+sD_h + 1}\right]$ can be obtained in closed form. The calculations for $\int \Phi_v(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau, \int \Phi_h(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau$ can also be obtained in closed form with the help of a symbolic processor, after proposing $u(t)$ as a cubic spline over a grid $\{t_0, t_1,\cdots, t_n\}$ of base points, being then $u(t)= u(u_0, u_1,\cdots, u_n,t)$.

Finally we can solve the maximization problem

$$
\max_{u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_n}\int_T (x_v^2(t,u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_n)-\rho^2 x_h^2(t,u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_n)) dt\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \|u\| \le u_{max}
$$

Follows a simplified MATHEMATICA script assuming $A_v=3,B_v=1,A_h=0.1,B_h =1,C_v=1,C_h=1,D_v=1,D_h=2, x_v(0) = \dot x_v(0)=x_h(0) = \dot x_h(0)=1$ and $u$ as a linear spline.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
parms = Thread[{Dv, Dh, Av, Ah, Bv, Bh, Cv, Ch, uv0, uh0, duv0, 
 duh0} -> {1, 2, 1/2, 3, 1/10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}];
tmin = 0;
tmax = 3;
n = 5;
tau0 = 100;
dt = (tmax - tmin)/n;
For[k = 1, k <= n + 1, k++, t0[k] = tmin + dt (k - 1)];
nt = n + 1;
U0 = Table[u0[k], {k, 1, nt}];
ut[u1_, u2_, t1_, t2_, t_] := u1 + (u2 - u1)/(t2 - t1) (t - t1)
uf[t_] := Piecewise[
Table[{ut[u0[k], u0[k + 1], t0[k], t0[k + 1], t], t0[k] <= t < t0[k + 1]}, {k, 1, n}]];
passivationfilter = tau0/(tau0 s + 1);
Phivt[t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[
  passivationfilter (Av s^2 + Bv s + Cv)/(s^2 + Dv s + 1) /. parms, s, t];
Phiht[t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[
  passivationfilter (Ah s^2 + Bh s + Ch)/(s^2 + Dh s + 1) /. parms, s, t];

Xvtau = Assuming[Join[{tau, t}, U0] \[Element] Reals, 
Integrate[Phivt[tau - t]*uf[t], {t, 0, tau}]] + InverseLaplaceTransform[(s uv0 + duv0)/(s^2 + Dv s + 1) /. parms, s, tau];
Xhtau = Assuming[Join[{tau, t}, U0] \[Element] Reals, 
Integrate[Phiht[tau - t]*uf[t], {t, 0, tau}]] + InverseLaplaceTransform[(s uh0 + duh0)/(s^2 + Dh s + 1) /. parms, s, tau];

TXvtau = Table[Abs[Xvtau /. {tau -> tmin + dt/2 (k - 1)}], {k, 1, 2 n + 1}] // ComplexExpand;
TXhtau = Table[Abs[Xhtau /. {tau -> tmin + dt/2 (k - 1)}], {k, 1, 2 n + 1}] // ComplexExpand;

rho = 10;
Umax = 1;
sol = NMaximize[{TXvtau.TXvtau - rho^2 TXhtau.TXhtau, U0.U0 <= Umax}, U0, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

Xvtau0 = Re[Xvtau /. sol[[2]]];
Xhtau0 = Re[Xhtau /. sol[[2]]];
Plot[{Xvtau0, Xhtau0}, {tau, tmin, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, PlotRange -> All]
U0t = Table[{tmin + dt (k - 1), u0[k]} /. sol[[2]], {k, 1, nt}];
ListLinePlot[U0t, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All]
```

Follow two plots: in the first in blue $x_v$ and red $x_h$ and for the second, in black $u$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry to take more of your time, but could you tell me what the rho^2 term is for? How did you select it? Thanks!

Comment: $\rho$ is squared to assure positiveness and  it is used as a penalty regarding the reduction of $x_h^2$